# Error while selecting radio button option using protractor and cucumberjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, ui-automation, cucumberjs

I am new to the world of automating tests on angular pages.
The framework I am using is protractor, but I am clubbing it with cucumberjs.

I am trying to click on a radio button. This is how the element looks like in the DOM :-

```
<div>
<input class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" type="radio" ng-click="setTestOrValid(p)" value="Valid" ng-model="p.testOrValidDisplay" name="341">
Valid
<input class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" type="radio" ng-click="setTestOrValid(p)" value="Invalid" ng-model="p.testOrValidDisplay" name="342">
Invalid (Test/Junk)
</div>
```

Following is the function which I have written to be able to click on it :-

```
sut.browser.findElements(sut.by.css('[ng-click="setTestOrValid(p)"]')).then(function(elements){
  for (i=0; i < elements.length; i++){
    elements[i].getAttribute('value').then(function(value){
      if (value == 'Invalid') {
        elements[i].click();
      }
    })
  }
});
```

The code above throws an error :-

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined
```

Would you please help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get to your element in one go using a CSS selector:

```
var elm = $("input[type=radio][value=Invalid]");
elm.click();
```

Or, you can filter all radiobuttons by model and [`filter()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.filter):

```
var elm = element.all(by.model("p.testOrValidDisplay")).filter(function(elm) {
    return elm.getAttribute("value").then(function (value) {
        return value === "Invalid";
    });
}).first();
elm.click();
```

Comment: Thanks alecxe!

1. Since, I am not using jasmine but cucumberjs this is how it worked for me :-
var elm = sut.browser.findElement(sut.by.css("input[type=radio][value=Invalid]"));
  elm.click();
How did you come up with this css, is there any resource I can use to improve my skills?

Comment: 2. The other suggestion you gave me of filter method does not work for me. This is how I had altered it :-

  var els = sut.browser.findElements(sut.by.css('[ng-click="setTestOrValid(p)"]'));
  els.filter(function(elements){
    return elements.getAttribute('value').then(function(value){
            return value == 'Invalid';
    });
  }).click();

  When I run this, it gives me the following error :-

  TypeError: sut.browser.findElements(...).filter is not a function

  What am I missing?

Comment: 3. If I use element.all (even $ for that matter) instead of findElements then I get an error :-

ReferenceError: element is not defined

How should I access the global protractor objects while using cucumberjs?

Comment: @Karishma 1. This just came from an experience, attribute checks are simple in CSS selectors: `[attr="value"]` and you can omit the quotes if attribute value is alphanumeric. 2. Yeah, the `filter()` is protractor specific, there is no `filter()` for the regular `findElements` results. 3. Sorry, have not used protractor and cucumber before. Thanks!

Comment: @Karishma let's avoid solving follow up problems in comments. If you have an additional question and you cannot solve it on your own, consider creating a new stackoverflow question. Thanks!